# How to solve this error (This class should provide a default constructor)?

Tags: java, android, wifi

Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)

I am create wifi direct broadcast receiver. Its getting error from signed apk generated time. I attached my code. This class work for receiving same router devices list. and getting offline connection.

```
 public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private WifiP2pManager manager;
        private WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
        private MainActivity activity;
        String TAG = "WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver";
        /**
    //     * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
    //     * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
    //     * @param activity activity associated with the receiver
         */


        public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel,MainActivity activity) {
            super();
            this.manager = manager;
            this.channel = channel;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

         /*
         * (non-Javadoc)s
         * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
         * android.content.Intent)
         */

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "P2P action - " + action);
            if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
                int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
                if(state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                    // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
                    activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
                    activity.resetData();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
            } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
                // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
                // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
                // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
                if(manager != null) {
                    manager.requestPeers(channel, (WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "P2P peers changed");

            } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
                if(manager == null) {
                    return;
                }
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                if(networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    // we are connected with the other device, request connection
                    manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel,activity);

                }else{
                    // It's a disconnect
                    activity.resetData();
                }
            } else  if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
                DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
                if(fragment != null) {
                    fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you got any constructor defined for `BroadcastReceiver` class?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I didn't used these classe

Comment: Yes you did. You extended it. Does it have a default constructor? Clearly not.

Answer (score 2):

The class `BroadcastReceiver` does not have a default constructor, but your `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver` class is calling it implicitly in the default constructor `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver()`:

```
public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver() {
    // implicit super() call here, calls BroadcastReceiver(), which doesn't exist
}
```

You need to either call one of `BroadcastReceiver`'s existing constructors via `super(...)`, with whatever arguments are appropriate, or provide a default one.

Answer (score -3):

Add a public constructor with no parameters. The constructor is having parameters. Add another constructor with no parameters just a empty constructor.

```
public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(){

    }
```